# It it possible to have private files in a public repository?

Tags: github, github-actions

I plan to release an open-source application on GitHub that includes Actions to build the executables and docker image.

In addition to these Actions, I would like to set one "just for me" (update my own docker container with the new image, as a separate Action). The Action YAML file would be part of the repository, but stay private.

Is this something doable, or are public repositories files all public?

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/questions/559975/git-private-files-in-public-repositories help?

Comment: Or this? https://github.community/t/can-i-make-parts-of-my-private-repository-public/3112

Comment: Due to the nature of git, it's not possible to "hide" content from someone who's allowed to clone the repository. Github actions has something calles "repository dispatch" which *might* be useful to trigger an action on a private repository (with the private files) whenever the public one gets built. But that requires a private access token which would then live in the public repository, which would be problematic again,

Comment: You can divide data to public and private and save separately in the public repo and GitHub Actions encrypted secrets.

Answer (score 2):

A pseudo-answer to keep track of existing information outside of SO:

> Hiding specific information in a git repository is not one of the things it's designed for. AFAIK it is also not possible. One approach that might work, though I have never tried this, is to have a public and a private git repo, and have the private repo be a git submodule for the public one. This might be more hassle then it's worth though, and might be confusing at points causing you to put private data in the public repo. So perhaps you should just have tow completely separate repos.

(source: https://superuser.com/a/559978/60006)

> No, you cannot have different public/private settings within one
> repository.
>
> The closest thing I can think of would be to keep the repositories
> separate and use submodules to create a unified directory tree, but I
> can’t judge if that makes sense for your workflow.

(source: https://github.community/t/can-i-make-parts-of-my-private-repository-public/3112/2)